# Ruby on Rails - Using LogServer for Remote Logging in log4r using ROMP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, log4r

I am a complete newbie in working with a Ruby on Rails (RoR) application. I am trying to set up a LogServer and tried running the example available on github : https://github.com/colbygk/log4r/blob/master/examples/logserver.rb and the https://github.com/colbygk/log4r/blob/master/examples/logclient.rb.

But I knew that ROMP was required for setting up a LogServer, so I downloaded the ROMP tarball and expanded it here : /usr/lib/ruby/1.8

But still when I tried running the logserver.rb program in the terminal, I get :

"/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/log4r/configurator.rb:204:in `new': LogServer not supported. ROMP is required (RuntimeError) from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/log4r/configurator.rb:204:in`decode_logserver' ...."

Any idea on how to properly install ROMP on my machine???
I am using Ubuntu 10.04, ruby1.8 and rails 2.2.3.

Thanks in Advance ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this link:  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/103958

After downloading and extracting the ROMP tarball ...

```
cd romp-0.2
ruby extconf.rb
make
```

This will compile the ROMP C extension. Now you need to install it into your ruby directory. On my Windows/Cygwin bastard box this is found in ...

```
/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
```

The ROMP .rb files go directly into this directory, and the compiled .so goes into the

```
/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin
```

directory.

Please note that I have not tried this installation myself, but I hope
you get the general idea

Comment: I also went over the same link before I pasted this question. I could not find the appropiate folder to put the .so files on my Ubuntu machine but after a lot of monkeying around I finally got it. Romp is working beautifully now ...:-)

Comment: :) good job Krishnan! I would say that Ubuntu is much better than Cygwin ... ^_^